# Mocha not finish when using emit socket io

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, socket.io, mocha.js

Hello i'm using Mocha to run Unit test, everything is OK until testing a method using `io.emit`, you can see my code below:

```
var emit = (type, to, content, url) => {
    var f = false;
    var io = require("../index").io;
    var socketIds = global.socketIds;
    if (socketIds && socketIds[to]) {
        let sockets = socketIds[to];
        for(let item of sockets){
            io.to(item).emit(type, { type: type, content: content, url: url });
            f = true;
        }
    }
    return f;
};
```

and this is my test code:

```
describe("create new notification with offline account", () => {
    it("it should be return a notification and offline status", done => {
            const save = global.socketIds;
            global.socketIds = {};
            callService(expected.notification, result => {
                Notification.findOne(expected.notification, (err, noti) => {
                    expect(result.online).to.equal(expected.online);
                    expect(noti).to.exist;
                    global.socketIds = save;
                    done();
                });
            });
        });
});
```

[Mocha not finish and stop here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpcQS.png)

- Mocha version: 5.2.0

Comment: Unless I'm missing something obvious, how does that `emit` function relate to the testing code?

Comment: sorry i don't understand. what is your mind?

Comment: How does `emit` impact the testing code? I don't see it referenced. Where is `io.emit` used?

Comment: i don't know why but i was try `process.exit(1)` then mocha was finish

Comment: With asynchronous code you need to ensure that the `done()` method is reliably called. Can you verify that's happening? It's not clear what `Notification.findOne` does or if it's going to call that block properly. Remember Mocha supports Promises which can really simplify your asynchronous code, especially when you use `async`/`await`.

Comment: it isn't correct bro :( coverage file not change